# Oracle get distict values from array of type number

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an array type defined below -

```
TYPE INPUT_ARRAY_NUM IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

I have defined a variable of the above type as -

```
temp INPUT_ARRAY_NUM;
```

Populated them with below values -

```
temp(0) := 1;
temp(1) := 1;
temp(2) := 3;
```

How can I get distinct values (1, 3) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a **NESTED TABLE** and use `MULTISET` operation.

The **DISTINCT** keyword in the `MULTISET` operation removes the **duplicates** from the set.

For example,

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  3    l_tab1 t_tab := t_tab(1,1,3,3,5,5);
  4  BEGIN
  5    l_tab1 := l_tab1 MULTISET INTERSECT DISTINCT l_tab1;
  6    FOR i IN l_tab1.first .. l_tab1.last
  7    LOOP
  8      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Distinct values are '||l_tab1(i));
  9    END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /
Distinct values are 1
Distinct values are 3
Distinct values are 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Dosen't work throws wrong number or types of arguments in call error.

Comment: @RAZER It was a simple example, I thought you could figure out how to make it practically work. Anyway, I have added a working example now, check it out.

Comment: @RAZER No problem :-) Now you know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet will print the distinct values of an array You can play around with it.

```
FOR y IN ( SELECT DISTINCT column_value
FROM TABLE ( CAST (newsites As siteArray ))
)
LOOP
Dbms_Output.Put_Line ('VAlue = ' || y.column_value);
END LOOP;
```

https://community.oracle.com/thread/648610?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this. This is one of the method to get distinct array values from input

    set serveroutput on;
    DECLARE
    TYPE INPUT_ARRAY_NUM
    IS
      TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
      tab INPUT_ARRAY_NUM;
    BEGIN
      SELECT DISTINCT * BULK COLLECT
      INTO tab
      FROM
        ( SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
        );
      FOR i IN tab.first..tab.last
      LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(tab(i));
      END LOOP;
    END;

-------------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------------------------
anonymous block completed
1
2
3
-------------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------------------------
```